# use task<string> method in overriden

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I would like to know whats the ideal way to call a method that returns a Task inside an override method?

For example:

```
public Task<string> GetName()
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
      return "Foo";
    });
}
```

In one of my methods I would just simple do this:

```
public async Task<string> DoSomething()
{
    var res = await GetName();
    return res + " rocks";
}
```

But now I am facing a situation where there is a method delcared like this:

```
public virtual string DoSomething()
{
  //does something...
}
```

In my inheritance I need to override this method and do some stuff and call a Task method, so my first thought was to do this:

```
public override async Task<string> DoSomething()
{
    //does something...
    base.DoSomething();

    var res = await GetName();
    return res + " rocks";
}
```

This clearly isnt possible since I changed the return value from a overriden method from string to Task string...

How should I solve my problem?

(Note: I cannot modify the base class, since its not mine. Its an external libary.)

Comment: Why do you want to override/write the original method? Make the change in the original method instead and be on your way?

Comment: I cannot modify the base class, since its not mine. Its a external libary.

Comment: This doesn't make sense - if you need to return a different type to the method you're overriding, then you shouldn't be overriding that method because you are trying to do something *other than what that method is supposed to do*. What are you actually trying to do? Drop the abstract stuff and ask about the *actual problem*.

Comment: I'd suggest not using the same DoSomething() as the external library then. Write a wrapper, call DoSomething() in that wrapper function and in your program, call the wrapper function you created instead of directly calling the external library's function

Comment: @AntP I am trying to fetch the return value of an Task<string> method, I normally do this by writing async in method header and use the await keyword, but writing the async keyword C#/.NET forces me to return a Task<string> instead of a normal string. So I had to change the signature which isnt possible since its a overriden method.

Comment: @user3036342 - cannot do this since I am never calling this method, the method gets called by an third application my application just gets rigistered to the third application and calls those methods that I have overwritten.

Comment: So you're never in control anyway? That sucks. I would recommend quitting your job then and moving to Alaska. A good day's worth of hard labour is very rewarding and you're always in control of what you're doing in situations like that. So sorry to hear.

Comment: @user3036342 I can only modify the GetName method in my above example, it fetches data and delivers it to this libary, lets say I am the middleman.

Comment: If you want any meaningful answers to this you're going to have to stop talking in abstract terms and specify the actual problem; i.e. what *actual* goal are you trying to achieve, what class are you inheriting, what method are you overriding and what is it for and what *actual code* are you trying to get it to execute? You need to talk in concrete terms because right now the answer is simply "you can't and you shouldn't want to." Stop talking about `Foo` and `Bar` and return types and start talking about the actual concrete problem.

Comment: @AntP It would appear as if he is trying to be fancy and making his add-on script (which is what I can deduce from this), to act asynchronously whereas the 2 x 3rd party apps he has no control over, are synchronous. My feeling? stop trying to force a square block in a round hole. If he had access/control over the 3rd party applications, it would be possible, but he is trying to code with his hands tied behind his back just because he wants async capabilities

Comment: @user3036342 - you are getting pretty close, I am doing this since I dont want my application to hang because of synchronous methods when a third libary is accessing data.

Comment: @RandRandom Not knowing how your application actually hooks into the 3rd application that calls the external library, I can't help much, but if your goal is not to have your application "lock up" while waiting for data, I suggest looking into Threading your UI separate to the calls you have to make to update it and forget about calling stuff async

Comment: `Task<string>` is an actual return type, and different from just `string`. So both methods have a different signature making it impossible that they overwrite each other.

Comment: @user3036342 In my head async == threading, so I thought thats the way to do it with Task Parallel Libary, seems like I have to rethink my implementation to not block the UI.

Comment: async helps, but in this case, since you have absolutely NO CONTROL over the 3rd party software, you will be forced to use Threading to do what you want not to block the UI. Otherwise, the multiple other answers that shows the wrapper concept I talked about should work as wekk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
public override string DoSomething()
{
    //does something...
    base.DoSomething();

    return GetName().Result;
}
```

**Warning: this can cause a deadlock**

See [Don't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: What is the point of writing an `async` method and executing it synchronously?

Comment: He wants the function to return Task<string>, however, depending on what the actual issue is, I agree that this will work

Comment: it may cause a deadlock

Comment: [Don't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: @ken2k The base method expects a sync result, so it's impossible to not block. He can't modify the base-method, so the link you provide does not apply

Comment: @Kenneth Of course it does. You'll end up with code that seems to work but is in fact broken. You'll see when an exception will occur in the async call... You can't just transform async code in sync code this way, it's not how the whole thing works. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx Still downvoting this answer as it doesn't warn at all about the subject